# Temperature of i5 6200U

Tags: cpu

I've Dell Inspiron 5559, 
Core i5 6th generation
4+4= 8 G.B ram
Intel Graphics 520. My C.P.U's temperature is showing 60 degree Celsius, is it normal temperature even I do not play any game.

Comment: That is normal. Max temp is 100C

Answer (score 1):

60c is not uncommon with laptops, as their cooling isn't going to be as good as a large desktop with plenty of airflow.  Since it's the "U" model and the whole point of those is that the processor is under the standard clockspeed for the generation to save battery life, I'm betting this is just laptop cooling.  Your processor is fine.

Answer (score 0):

No,its not normal temperature...In many light usages like word,web browsing,power point,excel etc your temp. should be around 45-50 degree Celsius.. max upto 53 degree.. If you play games then 60 degree is normal temperature.

Comment: Welcome to Super User and thank you for your answer. Can you cite a reference or resource to back this assertion up? :)

Comment: @Gamer Beast if this were my desktop running at 60 all day, I would be worried.  But modern laptop CPUs are intentionally designed and binned to stick to that temp.